# Retrieve gaps in dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve gaps in time-series data. Below is my example.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
    ([ID] int, [DATE] DATE)
;

INSERT INTO MYTABLE
    ([ID], [DATE])
VALUES
    (1, '2022-01-01'),
    (1, '2022-02-01'),
    (1, '2022-03-01'),
    (1, '2022-04-01'),
    (1, '2022-05-01'),
    (1, '2022-06-01'),
    (1, '2022-10-01'),
    (1, '2022-11-01'),
    (1, '2022-12-01'),
    (2, '2022-01-01'),
    (2, '2022-02-01'),
    (2, '2022-03-01'),
    (2, '2022-04-01'),
    (2, '2022-05-01'),
    (2, '2022-06-01'),
    (2, '2022-07-01'),
    (2, '2022-08-01'),
    (2, '2022-10-01'),
    (2, '2022-11-01'),
    (2, '2022-12-01')
;
```

The date field follows a convention where the day is always 1st of the month.  For the above example, the gaps would be the following.

```
| ID |       DATE |
|----|------------|
|  1 | 2022-07-01 |
|  1 | 2022-08-01 |
|  1 | 2022-09-01 |
|  2 | 2022-09-01 |
```

How would I write a query to return the above results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one straightforward way. First you generate all dates between min and max in MYTABLE:

```
with min_max(min_dt, max_dt) as ( 
    select min([DATE]), max([DATE]) from MYTABLE
), all_dt(d) as (
    select min_dt from min_max
    union all 
    select DATEADD(month, 1, d) from all_dt
    where d < (select max_dt from min_max)
)
select y.d 
from all_dt y
```

Now you can take the cartesian product between that and the set of users in MYTABLE

```
with min_max(min_dt, max_dt) as ( 
    select min([DATE]), max([DATE]) from MYTABLE
), all_dt(d) as (
    select min_dt from min_max
    union all 
    select DATEADD(month, 1, d) from all_dt
    where d < (select max_dt from min_max)
)
select x.id, y.d 
from all_dt y, (select distinct [ID] as id from MYTABLE) as x
```

I used the "," join since I was not sure whether SQL-server supports explicit CROSS JOIN. Finally you can subtract all existing rows from that set:

```
with min_max(min_dt, max_dt) as ( 
    select min([DATE]), max([DATE]) from MYTABLE
), all_dt(d) as (
    select min_dt from min_max
    union all 
    select DATEADD(month, 1, d) from all_dt
    where d < (select max_dt from min_max)
)
select x.id, y.d 
from all_dt y, (select distinct [ID] as id from MYTABLE) as x
except
select [ID], [DATE] from MYTABLE
```

I would advise you to avoid identifiers like DATE and ID, but I assume this is just an example

EDIT: CROSS JOIN apparently works according to my fiddle, so you can rephrase that as:

```
...
SELECT x.id, y.d 
FROM all_dt y 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT distinct [ID] AS id FROM MYTABLE) AS x
EXCEPT
SELECT [ID], [DATE] FROM MYTABLE
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03c144940a57fe33a9dafd44666e74d5)